# How To Change the Style or Design of Layered Navigation Search Filter?

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, search, design

Can you please help me how to change the style or design of filter search.

I attached my current filter image and amazon filter image.
Please help me how to change this design?
I want my filter exact as amazon.
[image][image]
Thanks for answer in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are some free extensions are available,

> If you want to develop to your own then its a long process that's why
>   I suggest you free extensions

https://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/free-ajax-layered-navigation-extension.html

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multiple-select-in-layered-navigation-filters.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am looking for a process to do it manually:)